# uploading .ipa file for appcenter distribution using Xamarin

Tags: xamarin.ios, visual-studio-app-center

I am trying to use AppCenter to distribute my app to iOS beta testers.

I have included the nuget packages for Microsoft.AppCenter and Microsoft.AppCenter.Distribute

I followed the developer.xamarin instructions for creating an IPA

An IPA did not appear in the Bin > iOS Device > Ad Hoc (or Release) folder as expected.  An application (.exe) file was created.
This is most likely the area I need help on.

In AppCenter I selected Distribute and got to the Upload a Build screen, I could not find an IPA file on my computer.

when pressing the Where Can I Find my IPA file? link, I was transferred to https://openapi.appcenter.ms/, which I didn't understand how to use to find the file.  Perhaps this link is incorrect or someone can tell me how to use these apis to find the file?

I have never connected my Windows Visual Studio Xamarin to a Mac. LivePlayer on an iPhone works beautifully. I was hoping to get to be able to distribute my app without using a physical Mac.

Thank you for any help.  If you can point me towards other tutorials on setting up and using AppCenter to distribute to iPhone beta users, I would appreciate it.

Comment: are you using App Center to build your app?  Or are you building locally in VS and only want to distribute via AC?

Comment: I am developing in VS and only want to distribute to testers in AppCenter

Answer (score 0):

To order generate an .ipa file for distribution a Mac needs to be involved in the build process.

If you do not have access to a Mac for local development and the application source code is located in a git repository hosted in GitHub, BitBucket, or Visual Studio Team Services, then you can [link App Center to the git repository](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/build/connect) and [configure App Center to perform the build](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/build/ios/first-build/xamarin/index) for distribution purposes.